# Is the ban warning too strict?

Tags: support, post-ban

I want to ask a new question and get the warning

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.

But I asked 9 questions so far, don't have any deleted questions in my *recent deleted questions* link and **none** of my questions has a negative score. 3 of them have upvotes.

Is the warning about getting banned too strict or am I really on the edge of getting banned?

Comment: You have 4 deleted questions with scores of 0,1,0,-2. Doesn't seem too bad to me.

Comment: I came here with the same question after I got the warning.  I so far posted just one question on the SU site. It does have -1 score. Is a single occurrence really enough to spot the pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have asked a total of 14 questions on this site, two of which were last august and were migrated to [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) ([1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68363/view-waypoints-in-osm))([2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68364/osm-personal-points-of-interest)) and another in march that went to [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41947/easy-record-gps-coordinates-in-openstreetmap).  Prior to that you have a deleted question and a two closed duplicates.

It is possible that you are on the edge of hitting the automatic ban (which we have no control of) and the detection system is trying to warn you to make sure that what you are asking really is suitable and you are asking on the correct site.

I can't see anything that can be done to improve the situation beyond making sure that you read the [help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) to ensure that what you are asking will be favourably received.

Comment: I try to do better. But what can I say: I was young and needed the answers.

Comment: As Oliver has said you are probably fine, it's just something you need to keep in mind.  You have massive rep on other sites so there's no doubt that you are a good contributor but that doesn't get taken into account here, mores the pity.  Your intentions are obviously good, but this is one thing we have no control over.